# 32 bit representations and shifting

Tags: computer-science, binary

If 7 in 32 bit binary form is:

```
 00000000000000000000000000000111
```

I would like to perform right arithmetic shift (>>) by 16 so what would the binary representation look like then? I'm a bit confused on this.

Comment: Hint: right shift in binary is equivalent to taking the integer part of the number divided by $\,2\,$, so the result will be $\,\displaystyle\left\lfloor\frac{7}{2^{16}}\right\rfloor\,$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With each arithmetic shift right, the lowest bit falls off the end, the other bits move down one position, and the sign bit (0 here) propagates down. So after only 3 shifts, all bits are 0, and each of the remaining shifts result in zero as well. So: the result is 0 in every bit position.